# Give I/P and O/P to .EXE using Bash Script

Tags: bash

I want to echo output of ./factorial and give input to the same ./factorial in the bash script dynamically. Please suggest me command line or full code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Hello" | tee -a /dev/stdin
```

Comment: I have to run ./factorial exe file and echo whatever output is I m getting and based on the output I want to pass input. Plz help me, I am new to linux.

Comment: In general, piping the output of a program to its input is not recommended, as it can lead to lockups, that is, if the application outputs too much content, the `write` function will block until the "receiving" application reads from its input; however, since the "receiving" application is the same, it's currently blocking on output, unable to read from its input. \\\\ You should consider other options. What you are trying to do makes sense, but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.